# Optimizing `data.table::fread` speed advice

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am experiencing read speeds that I believe are much slower than should be expected when trying to read a fairly large file in R with `fread`.

The file is ~60m rows x 147 columns, out of which I am only selecting 27 columns, directly in the `fread` call using `select`; only 23 of the 27 are found in the actual file. (Probably I inputted some of the strings incorrectly but I guess that matters less.)

```
data.table::fread("..\\TOI\\TOI_RAW_APextracted.csv",
                     verbose = TRUE,
                     select = cols2Select)
```

The system being used is an Azure VM with a 16-core Intel Xeon and 114 GB of RAM, running Windows 10.
I'm also using R 3.5.2, RStudio 1.2.1335 and data.table 1.12.0

I should also add that the file is a csv file that I have transferred onto the local drive of the VM, so there is no network / ethernet involved. I am not sure how Azure VMs work and what drives they use, but I would assume it's something equivalent to an SSD. Nothing else is running / being processed on the VM at the same time.

Please find below the `verbose` output of `fread`:

```
omp_get_max_threads() = 16 omp_get_thread_limit() = 2147483647 DTthreads = 0 RestoreAfterFork = true Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open [01] Check arguments   Using 16 threads (omp_get_max_threads()=16, nth=16)   NAstrings = [<<NA>>]   None of the NAstrings look like numbers.   show progress = 1   0/1 column will be read as integer [02] Opening the file   Opening file ..\TOI\TOI_RAW_APextracted.csv   File opened, size = 49.00GB (52608776250 bytes).   Memory mapped ok [03] Detect and skip BOM [04] Arrange mmap to be \0 terminated   \n has been found in the input and different lines can end with different line endings (e.g. mixed \n and \r\n in one file). This is common and ideal. [05] Skipping initial rows if needed   Positioned on line 1 starting: <<"POLNO","ProdType","ProductCod>> [06] Detect separator, quoting rule, and ncolumns   Detecting sep automatically ...   sep=','  with 100 lines of 147 fields using quote rule 0   Detected 147 columns on line 1. This line is either column names or first data row. Line starts as: <<"POLNO","ProdType","ProductCod>>   Quote rule picked = 0  fill=false and the most number of columns found is 147 [07] Detect column types, good nrow estimate and whether first row is column names Number of sampling jump points = 100 because (52608776248 bytes from row 1 to eof) / (2 * 85068 jump0size) == 309216   Type codes (jump 000)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA57777777555555552222AAAAAA25755555577555757AA5AA5AAAAA5555AAA2A...2222277555 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 001)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777555577555777AA5AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277555 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 002)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA5AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277555 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 003)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA5AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277775 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 010)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA5AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277775 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 031)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA7AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277775 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 098)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA7AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277775 Quote rule 0   Type codes (jump 100)    : A5AA5555A5AA5AAAA5777777757777775A5A5AAAAAAA7777775577555777AA7AA5AAAAA7555AAAAA...2222277775 Quote rule 0   'header' determined to be true due to column 2 containing a string on row 1 and a lower type (int32) in the rest of the 10045 sample rows   =====   Sampled 10045 rows (handled \n inside quoted fields) at 101 jump points   Bytes from first data row on line 2 to the end of last row: 52608774311   Line length: mean=956.51 sd=35.58 min=823 max=1063   Estimated number of rows: 52608774311 /
956.51 = 55000757   Initial alloc = 60500832 rows (55000757 + 9%) using bytes/max(mean-2*sd,min) clamped between [1.1*estn, 2.0*estn]  
===== [08] Assign column names [09] Apply user overrides on column types   After 0 type and 124 drop user overrides : 05000005A0005AA0A0000770000077000A000A00000000770700000000000000A00A000000000000...0000000000 [10] Allocate memory for the datatable   Allocating 23 column slots (147 - 124 dropped) with 60500832 rows [11] Read the data   jumps=[0..50176), chunk_size=1048484, total_size=52608774311 |--------------------------------------------------| |==================================================|   jumps=[0..50176), chunk_size=1048484, total_size=52608774311 |--------------------------------------------------| |==================================================| Read 54964696 rows x 23 columns from 49.00GB (52608776250 bytes) file in 30:26.810 wall clock time [12] Finalizing the datatable   Type counts:
       124 : drop      '0'
         3 : int32     '5'
         7 : float64   '7'
        13 : string    'A'
=============================
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map 48.996GB file
   0.035s (  0%) sep=',' ncol=147 and header detection
   0.001s (  0%) Column type detection using 10045 sample rows
   6.000s (  0%) Allocation of 60500832 rows x 147 cols (9.466GB) of which 54964696 ( 91%) rows used
1820.775s (100%) Reading 50176 chunks (0 swept) of 1.000MB (each chunk 1095 rows) using 16 threads    + 1653.728s ( 91%) Parse to row-major thread buffers (grown 32 times)    +   22.774s (  1%) Transpose    + 
144.273s (  8%) Waiting
  24.545s (  1%) Rereading 1 columns due to out-of-sample type exceptions
1826.810s        Total Column 2 ("ProdType") bumped from 'int32' to 'string' due to <<"B810">> on row 14
```

Basically, I would like to find out if this is just normal or if there is anything I can do to improve these reading speeds. Based on various benchmarks I've seen around and my own experience and intuition with fread using smaller files, I would have expected this to be read in much much quicker.

Also I was wondering if the multi-core capabilities are fully being used, as I have heard that under Windows this might not always be straightforward. My knowledge around  this topic is pretty limited unfortunately, but it does appear from the `verbose` output that `fread` is detecting 16 cores.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but maybe specifying all the column classes with `colClasses` could save time. Also there is a `nThread` option

Comment: Jonny, I believe `nThread` defaults to `getDTthreads` which should be fine, but I will try overwriting it.
I have just tried several things and the behaviour seems to have gotten even stranger. Upon changing the name of the columns to be selected so that all 27 of them are found, the speed significantly increased to ~180secs. However 2 of the column types had to be bumped (reassigned) so I tired speeding it up further by specifying the column class just for those 2 columns through colClasses. However this significantly slowed the read process down ( I didn't wait to see exactly )

Comment: The speed up I mentioned above might be due to `fread`'s caching though. I have restarted the session now and cannot replicate the read speed of 180secs anymore. So the issue remains...

Comment: are you running this locally, or on a server? we have seen high parallelism may not be a good thing on busy servers

Comment: Michael, I am not sure to be honest, but I am inclined to say on a server based on what I've been told by colleagues.
I have now tried most of the advice given here, but I can see no material improvement.
My raw data volume has actually now increased (it's roughly 80GB, 80m rows x 147 columns, out of which only 27 get selected)

Comment: MichaelChirico, as a developer of data.table, could you actually please confirm if when using `select` within `fread`, all columns get read in anyway or not ?

I am thinking that maybe there is nothing wrong with my system and this is actually the normal time to read this data in, although the reading time has increased to 40-45 minutes now that my data has increased as described in my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

(1) If you are using Windows, use Microsoft Open R; even more so if the cloud is Azure. Actually, there may be coordination between Open R and Azure client. Because of Intel's MKL and Microsoft built in enhancements, I find Microsoft Open R faster on Windows.

(2) I suspect 'Select' and 'Drop' work after a full file read. Maybe read all the file, subset or filter afterward.

(3) I think a restart is overkill. I run gc thrice every so often like this: 'gc();gc();gc();'' I have heard others say this does nothing. But at least it makes me feel better. Actually, I notice it helps me on Windows.

(4) The latest versions of data.table fread are implementing 'YAML' . This looks promising.

(5) setDTthread(0) uses all the cores. Too much parellitization can work against you. Trying halving your cores.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.
In terms of the R distribution used on this VM, it says `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client\R_SERVER`, slightly different from the usual Microsoft Open R path I'm used to - I'm not sure if they're the same or equivalent.

With regards to (2), I now suspect this might be the case either, but I'd really like to find out if this is described anywhere or confirmed by the developers.

From some tests I conducted limiting the number of cores does not significantly improve performance in my case.